# How to create a one-page website?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I am fairly new to webpage designing and to learn about website layouts I was browsing YouTube and I came across [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKrY0o_3TqU) where the vlogger explains his top 5 favorite website designs.

At time `1:44` he begins talking of one-page designs and talks about [SplitSecnd](https://www.splitsecnd.com/). I like the way their background is designed.

I know how to give `div` elements a different background image or color but I want to know how can I create a similar or replicate their background ? Their background has image and a triangle cut out of it and then a new section begins :)

Any help on that would be appreciated. I would appreciate an explanation with some sample code :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title> Lot of Divs </title>
<style>

    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .content{
        width: 1280px;
        height: 800px;
        font-family: "Courier New",monospaced;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: white;
    }
    #div1{
        background-image: url("../img/mentalist-1.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #div2{
        background-image: url("../img/prisonbreak-1.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    p{
        text-align: justify;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class = "content" id="div1">
        <p>
            An infamous 'psychic' abandons his public persona, outing himself as a fake, to focus on his work as a consultant 
            for the California Bureau of Investigation in order to find "Red John," the madman who killed his wife and daughter.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class = "content" id="div2">
        <p>
            Structural Engineer Michael Scofield turns himself in to the Fox River Penitentiary in order to break out his brother Lincoln Burrows, 
            who is on death row for the murder of the Vice President's brother. 
            But Lincoln was set up by some of the Company (an agency formed by corrupt government officials) guys, 
            headed by General Jonathan Krantz. Michael breaks out from Fox River with his brother Lincoln and other convicts
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

background style similar to that of SplitSecnd

Get the two omages in the background to stick together (no white spaces at the bottom)

Comment: You should post some of your own code and demonstrate where you're stuck, otherwise this question will likely be closed for being "overly broad". You need to be more specific.

Comment: ok I will do it :) Gimme a few minutes :)

Comment: One thing you might be interested in looking at is parallax websites. Give it a Google :)

Comment: @Seer check the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SplitSecnd is built easier then you might think. They are stacking transparent *.png images. For example the first one is here: https://www.splitsecnd.com/assets/images/core/road_crop_v3-min.png

From there you can just stack them. Use a div with `position: absolute;`, `z-index: ...` and `top: ...px;`.

The higher your z-index is, the higher it will be on the 'stack' (closer you your screen, like a z-axis). The position top allows you to position div's underneath eachother (y-asis). You will have to use a value close to the image height and then fine-tune it.